# Vim unwanted jump to end of file after write

Tags: vim

When I write to a file with `:w`, vim sometimes (NOT ALWAYS) jumps to the end of the file after the write operation is complete. I don't understand why this happens. I've been going through my .vimrc to see if I have some kind of bug. My .vimrc is quite large so I don't include the full source here, I think the only parts of my .vimrc which are perhaps relevant to this question are the following parts:

```
nore ; :
inoremap jj <Esc>

" Automatically remove all trailing whitespace.
" Every time the user issues a :w command, Vim will automatically remove all
" trailing whitespace before saving
autocmd BufWritePre * :%s/\s\+$//e

" Restore cursor position
au BufReadPost *
            \ if line("'\"") > 0|
            \ if line("'\"") <= line("$")|
            \ exe("norm '\"")|
            \else|
            \exe "norm $"|
            \endif|
            \endif
```

However I don't see how these parts of my .vimrc can cause the jump behavior after writing, a full source of my .vimrc is available [here](http://macciocu.net/codeblog/?p=66). I hope somebody has an idea about what is causing the unwanted jump.

Comment: You can try out if these settings causes the problem by commenting out these lines.

Comment: I think when you save a file, the trailing whitespaces will be deleted. If there are trailing whitespaces and the end of a file, the cursor will jump to those spaces and remove them. So the cursor halts at the last changes made.

Comment: `autocmd BufWritePre * :%s/\s\+$//e` will move the cursor to each affected line.

Comment: Thx, that explains why it's not happening always!

Comment: @BimbaLaszlo, yes i figured that out, however as the behavior was not always detected, commenting out the lines still didn't show me if the issue was actually disappeared yes or no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a command from my `~/.vimrc`:

```
command! -range=% TR mark `|execute <line1> . ',' . <line2> . 's/\s\+$//'|normal! ``
```

The trick is to create mark ` before the trimming and jump back to it afterward.

You can change your `autocmd` to:

```
autocmd BufWritePre * :mark `|%s/\s\+$//e|normal! ``
```

Answer (score 0):

Even with @romainl's addition of the mark, this still isn't fully transparent:

- the view (of displayed lines) may still change (`winsaveview()` instead of a mark would fix that)
- the `:s` command clobbers the last search pattern

A plugin (like my [DeleteTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3967)) would provide a more robust solution. (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.)